# SBT : Overriding default test task

Tags: playframework, sbt, scoverage

In our play project, we are running scoverage coverageReport using the following command:

```
sbt clean coverage test coverageReport
```

Instead of the explicit coverageReport goal , I want to run the report as part of test goal itself , something like

```
sbt test
```

should automatically run the coverageReport as well

I am a **newbie** for sbt/play so I am trying something like

```
test = test ++ ScoverageKeys.coverageReport
```

and

```
  test in Test := {
    (test in Test).value
    ScoverageKeys.coverageReport.value
  }
```

and few other options but nothing worked.

Could some one let me know how to override default test config so that it runs the coverage and coverageReport too in addition to running tests?

It would be nice if **test** goal triggers **coverage** before starting tests and **coverageReport** after finishing tests,

I have also tried adding a command alias in MicroService.scala and in plugins.sbt as below but it didnt work even.

```
addCommandAlias("test", "coverage test coverageReport")
```

Any ideas on how to make it work would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Suresh

Comment: I'd check [Def.sequential](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#Using+Def.sequential), since standard SBT composition (as in your first two attempts) gives no guarantee about the execution order. Not sure if that will get you any further though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the below snippet

```
  .settings(
    test in Test := Def.sequential(
      test in Test,
      ScoverageKeys.coverageReport.toTask
    ).value
  )
```