# SBT: add command-line parsing to modify settings for existing tasks

Tags: scala, sbt

When running tasks (e.g., `test`, `jmh:run`), I often want to specify `javaOptions` which are tedious to type by hand (e.g., to dump program data).

This is my current approach:

```
// build.sbt
lazy val myProject = project
  ...
  .settings(
    ...
    Test / javaOptions ++= if (sys.props.get("dump").nonEmpty) Seq("-X...", ...) else Nil
  )
```

I can set system properties on sbt launch (e.g., `sbt -Ddump`) and then check them with `sys.props`, but changing these properties requires me to reload sbt. I would like to parse some arguments when the task is invoked, such that I can write `test -dump` and modify the `Test / javaOptions` setting accordingly.

Is this possible? Someone recommended I [override the default task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719983/sbt-overriding-default-test-task) but I'm having trouble figuring out what that would look like. I have a suspicion I need an `InputTask` for this, but also don't know what that'd look like.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to reload sbt, if you are running sbt in a shell, you will need to programtically call‚ sys.props.set